# jQuery Flot Pie Chart Doesn't Show

Tags: jquery, css, flot

I'm trying to make a pie chart with Flot but my pie chart won't show up.

Here's my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $( function() {

     var data = [
    {label: "Pause", data:150},
    {label: "No Pause", data:100},
    {label: "Sleeping", data:250}
];
var options = {
    series: {
        pie: {show: true}
    },
    legend: {
        show: false
    }
};

$.plot($("#pie-placeholder"), data, options);


    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="pie-placeholder" class="flot"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my css file:

```
.flot {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Nothing really hard but the pie chart won't appear.

Here is what my chart looks like now:

[image]

I don't have any error so I don't understand what's wrong.

Can you help me please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the [pie plugin](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/source/jquery.flot.pie.js).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ebm9k4o0/).

I see you're wrapping your code in

```
$( function () {
    // your code
} );
```

though I'm not sure why you're passing jQuery an anonymous function. Though the code will still run I'd remove it or if you were trying to do an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) ([immediately invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)) I'd do the following:

```
( function () {
    // your code
} )();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that you're including `jquery.flot.pie.js`. If you inspect the source of [Flot's pie chart example](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/series-pie/), you'll see that you need to include the pie chart flot plugin. Make sure you have the `jquery.flot.pie.js` file located with your other flot javascript files and add the line below after the `jquery.flot.js` script tag in your HTML header.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>
```